# How to read data from USB port

Tags: linux, usb, adapter, tty

I have a CANbus to USB adapter (`Softing CANusb`) that we are using for a project (see attached picture bellow). This device has Windows drivers and a Windows API in order to access the data in the CAN frames. There are no Linux drivers / API from the manufacturer.

However, for the application that we need the device, we need to be able to read this data in Linux. There is no driver for Linux but when plugging in the device it shows up in `lsusb` as ID `077e:000a`. I have tried to access the device from tty but there is no `/dev/ttyUSB*`.

I have opened the device and the USB controller used is a `NSC USBN9603-28M`. I have looked it up and it's not converting to serial or anything, it depends on how it got programmed from the guys that used it.

My question to you: Is there any way to access the USB port in Linux and read the raw data that is coming from it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there is always [libusb](http://www.libusb.org/) but you have to know what you are doing. You could start with reverse engineering the protocol by sniffing USB data traffic in Windows.

Comment: Do you know any good program to sniff USB data?

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/usbsnoop/files/SnoopyPro/